# iPhone 5 simulator and media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, iphone-5

i have seen the answer here on how to get the media query of iPhone5

***@media
    only screen and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (min-device-width: 960px) and (device-height: 640px),
    only screen and (max-device-height: 1136px) and (min-device-height: 960px) and (device-width: 640px) {
    /*** iPhone only */
}*

Problem is, i have tried several web based simulator for ipod touch, iphone4 and iphone 5.. they are not just accurate. i don't own any of this devices so how can i know if the div is aligned right or if it's showing right on those devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i found an alternative for this.

Use Google Chrome Inspect Element --> Settings --> User Agent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no substitution for the real thing.

Ask one of your friends to borrow their phone, or go into the local Apple Store (or retailer) and ask to try out the phone and visit your site to check.

If you're developing locally then copy your code across to http://codepen.io so that you have access from the store.